# elasticsearch range filter incorrect

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, range, elasticsearch-1.6.0

Everyone. This is a simple test code with the [elasitcsearch document url](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/_executing_filters.html)

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/_search?pretty'
```

> {
>         "took" : 3,
>         "timed_out" : false,
>         "_shards" : {
>           "total" : 5,
>           "successful" : 5,
>           "failed" : 0
>         },
>         "hits" : {
>           "total" : 2,
>           "max_score" : 1.0,
>           "hits" : [ {
>             "_index" : "customer",
>             "_type" : "external",
>             "_id" : "1",
>             "_score" : 1.0,
>             "_source":{"age":20,"balance":100000,"name":"Thomas.St.Wang"}
>           }, {
>             "_index" : "customer",
>             "_type" : "external",
>             "_id" : "2",
>             "_score" : 1.0,
>             "_source":{"age":19,"balance":10000,"name":"T.S.W"}
>           } ]
>         }
>       }

---

The following request is not the result i expect. Why.

```
 curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/customer/external/_search?pretty' -d 



{  
   "query":{  
      "filtered":{  
         "query":{  
            "match_all":{  

            }
         },
         "filter":{  
            "range":{  
               "balance":{  
                  "gte":9999,
                  "lte":100001
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

> { "took" : 2,   "timed_out" : false,   "_shards" : {
>       "total" : 5,
>       "successful" : 5,
>       "failed" : 0   },   "hits" : {
>       "total" : 0,
>       "max_score" : null,
>       "hits" : [ ]   } }

What's wrong with my query? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/customer/_mapping/external/field/balance'
```

> {"customer":{"mappings":{"external":{"balance":{"full_name":"balance","mapping":{"balance":{"type":"string"}}}}}}}

This is the answer. Because the balance filed is a string.
I need delete the index,and restart index it.